# Receiving deprecation warnings from GitHub when using the Spring Security Rest Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security-rest

I have a Grails 3 application that uses the spring-security-rest plugin version 2.0.0.RC1, using GitHub for user authentication.

I am seeing warnings from GitHub:

```
Your application used an access token as part of a query parameter to access an endpoint through the GitHub API:
    https://api.github.com/user
Please use the Authorization HTTP header instead as using the `access_token` query parameter is deprecated.
```

Is there a version where this is fixed that still works with Grails 3?

I believe the deprecation warnings become failures in November, 2020.

**Update:** Poking around pac4j I see in the OAuthConfiguration class there is a tokenAsHeader variable. If set, it adds the authorization token to the header when getting user information.

I'm not sure if this will work, but I added tokenAsHeader = true to application.groovy:

```
github {
  client = org.pac4j.oauth.client.GitHubClient 
  key = '${APP_KEY}' 
  secret = '${APP_SECRET}' 
  scope = 'user' 
  tokenAsHeader = true
  defaultRoles = ['ROLE_GITHUB'] 
}
```

I don't see a change in the debug output and I only receive deprecated warning emails periodically, so I'm not sure if this is a solution or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you could figure out, the OAuth clients aren't part of Spring Security REST itself, but come from Pac4j. Spring Security REST 2.0.0.RC1 ships with Pac4j 2.2.1, which is 2.5 years old. So it is possible that valid settings for clients back then, are being deprecated nowadays.

Your chances are:

1. Upgrade locally to a newer Pac4j version. It should work smoothly upgrading all the way through 4.0.0. In `build.gradle`:

   ```
   compile("org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.RC1") {
       exclude group: 'org.pac4j'
   }
   compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-core:3.8.3"
   compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-oauth:3.8.3"
   ```
2. Upgrade your application to Grails 4 and use Spring Security REST 3.0.1, which uses pac4j 3.8.3

Comment: I compared the pac4j 2.2.x version with the 3.8.x version to see if upgrading would change anything. I don't believe it will. They both provide the same tokenAsHeader variable, but neither version sets it by calling setTokenAsHeader() for the GitHub client (in both versions they do set it for OrcidClient, PayPalClient, and WordPressClient). I was hoping setting tokenAsHeader to true in application.groovy would pass this through to pac4j. I guess the only solution is to build local versions. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'm sorry if this is obvious, but how do I build my own version of the Spring Security Rest plugin? I made a change to pac4j and rebuilt (via mvn clean install), and modified the build.gradle for spring-security-rest to reference my version of pac4j. Now I need to rebuild Spring Security Rest and reference this new version from my grails application. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you need a custom Spring Security REST version. You can simply exclude the pac4j dependency and include your own. I'll update the answer with a sample snippet.

That being said, if the error is still present in pac4j, rather than fixing it locally, you should report the issue to pac4j and contribute your fix upstream.

Comment: I appreciate your help so much! Thank you! I am reporting the issue to pac4j ...